# How can you set a PowerShell output as a batch variable?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, token

I created a batch file that executes a PowerShell command. This should read out the capacity of the notebook battery. How can the result of the command be defined as a variable?

Something with tokens is needed for that, right? Can someone help me? In the end, CMDs/Natchs "echo" should output the result.

```
powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Class "BatteryFullChargedCapacity" -Namespace "ROOT\WMI").FullChargedCapacity"
```

Comment: FYI, there is no need to use [tag:powershell] for this task. Although regardless of which method you use to retrieve the WMI information, the linked duplicate question should provide the appropriate methodology.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Class "BatteryFullChargedCapacity" -Namespace "ROOT\WMI").FullChargedCapacity"') do set "var=%%a"
```

You can replace `var` with variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this batch code using `for in do` loop : [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

```
@echo off
Set PS_CMD=Powershell ^
"(Get-WmiObject -Class "BatteryFullChargedCapacity" -Namespace "ROOT\WMI"^).FullChargedCapacity"

@for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('%PS_CMD%') do set "var=%%a"
    echo %Var%
pause
```